# WTS: $X = (X \cap (C \setminus A)) \cup (X \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B \subset C$, with $A \subset B$. I want to show that for every subset $X$ of $C$, it follows: $X = (X \cap (C \setminus A)) \cup (X \cap B)$. Let

\begin{equation}\begin{split}
&~x \in (X \cap (C \setminus A)) \cup (X \cap B) \\
\Leftrightarrow&~x \in X \wedge (x \in C \setminus A \vee x\ \in B) \\
\Leftrightarrow&~x \in X \wedge~...\color{red}?... \\
\Leftrightarrow&~x \in X \wedge x \in C \\
\Leftrightarrow&~x \in X.
\end{split}\end{equation}

Comment: I'm missing everything.What does WTS mean? Which  A,B,C,X  ?  As written, if X is not empty but is disjoint from C and from B, then it is false.

Comment: The question is now edited. (WTS = want to show)

Comment: I suggest R.T.P. (Required To Prove) not WTS. It's common usage.

Comment: @user254665 I suggest to be explicit. Where I live not even _English_ is common usage for starting level math classes, let alone such abbreviations. And I've read quite some math, but never encountered either abbreviation.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster. I've often seen RTP in lecture and seminar but rarely in print. I prefer not to use abbreviations ,because there are too many of them and I can't expect someone else to know them all.

Comment: @user254665 Agree, that's what I said: be explicit, don't use abbreviations that might not be globally clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is fine, let me try and help you fill the gap in your proof.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$

You started out perfectly fine: calculate which $\;x\;$ are elements of the set on the right hand side, and then work towards $\;x \in X\;$.
$$\calc
    x \in (X \cap (C \setminus A)) \;\cup\; (X \cap B)
\op=\hint{definitions of $\;\cup, \cap, \setminus\;$}
    (x \in X \land x \in C \land x \not\in A) \;\lor\; (x \in X \land x \in B)
\op=\hint{$\;x \in C\;$ follows from $\;x \in X\;$ by the assumption $\;X \subseteq C\;$}
    (x \in X \land x \not\in A) \;\lor\; (x \in X \land x \in B)
\op=\hint{logic: extract common conjunct}
    x \in X \;\land\; (x \not\in A \lor x \in B)
\op=\hint{logic: rewrite -- to make the next step easier to see}
    x \in X \;\land\; (x \in A \then x \in B)
\op=\hint{RHS is true by the assumption $\;A \subseteq B\;$; simplify}
    x \in X
\endcalc$$

Therefore, by set extensionality, $\;(X \cap (C \setminus A)) \;\cup\; (X \cap B) \;=\; X\;$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (1):$\cap$ and $\cup$ are distributive over each other in the style of the distributive law of arithmetic. That is :  $p\cap (q\cup r)=(p\cap q)\cup (p\cap r)$ and $p\cup (q\cap r)=(p\cup q)\cap (p\cup r)$. Hint (2): $p\cap (q\backslash r)=(p\cap q)\backslash (p\cap r)$.

Comment: I still don't get the desired answer if I use your hints:
\begin{equation}
x \in X \wedge (x \notin (X \cap A) \vee x \in B)
\end{equation}
What am I missing here?

Comment: Since $X\subset C$ we have $X\cap (C\backslash A)=(X\cap C)\backslash (X\cap A)=X\backslash (X\cap A)=X\backslash A$.Since $A\subset B$ we have $X\cap B=(X\cap A)\cup (X\cap B)$.Combining these we have $(X\backslash A)\cup (X\cap A)\cup (X\cap B)=X\cup (X\cap B)=X$.